# woff2 のファイルの中身を確認したい

Tags: font

woff2 のファイルの中に、どのようなデータが入っているのかを確認したいため、その中身を表示したいと考えています。

素直に考えると、フォントファイルとは、文字(code point 列)と、それに対応するベクター等の画像データ、という形式をしていると思っていて、であるならば、その code point 列 -> 画像データ(バイナリ?)形式の hash 構造として、パースが可能だと思っています。

## 質問

woff2 のファイルの中身を確認するツール(できれば、コマンドラインツールが望ましい)には、どのようなものがありますでしょうか?

Answer (score 0):

WOFF2 ファイルのデータ仕様に関しては WOFF2 のサイトを参照すると良さそうです。

https://www.w3.org/TR/WOFF2/#FileStructure

中身の確認ですが、例えば「WOFF2 parser」で検索すると以下の npm パッケージが見つかりました。

https://www.npmjs.com/package/woff2-parser

> Usage:
>
> ```js
> var fs = require('fs');
> var parser = require('woff2-parser');
>
> fs.readFile('font.woff2', function (err, contents) {
>     if (err) throw err;
>     parser(contents).then(function (result) {
>         console.log(result);
>     });
> });
> ```
>
> Output:
>
> ```js
> {
>     ...
>     "name": {
>         "format": 0,
>         "nameRecords": {
>             "English": {
>                 "fontFamily": "Source Sans Pro",
>                 "fontSubFamily": "Regular",
>                 "uniqueFontId": "1.050;ADBE;SourceSansPro-Regular;ADOBE",
>                 "fullName": "Source Sans Pro",
>                 "version": "Version 1.050;PS Version 1.000;hotconv 1.0.70;makeotf.lib2.5.5900",
>                 "postscriptName": "SourceSansPro-Regular",
>                 "licenseUrl": "http://www.adobe.com/type/legal.html"
>             }
>         }
>     },
>     ...
> }
> ```